# What happened to the git bash prompt?

Tags: git, github

After typing `cd draft` at the prompt below in Git Bash

`C:\Users\Afonso\Documents\Github>`

I used to get the following prompt

`C:\Users\Afonso\Documents\Github\draft [master ≡]>`

Now, I'm getting this instead:

`C:\Users\Afonso\Documents\Github\draft [master ↑]>`

What does that change mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you referring to the up arrow ?

It states that you commited some changes to your local repository and you need to sync it with your remote repository (using `git push origin your-branch-name`.

An down arrow would mean that someone commited changes in your remote repository and you can sync it down to your local repository (using `git fetch` or `git pull`)